# How do I get certain values of a HTML attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to take the value of an attribute, process it and then replace a PHP variable with the value we receive at the end.

The data attribute is `data-id`, all I need assistance with is getting the value of data-id into Javascript on a `click event`, the rest I can do.

An example:

Person clicks an  tag with the data-id set as, say, 7. I'd then need to extract that 7 from the HTML code and into a Javascript variable so I can work with said value.

I hope this is clear enough

Comment: try this `$(selector).data('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#someelement').click(function(){
    $(this).data('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick.

```
$(selector).click(function(){
    var dataAttrId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // Your code goes here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
jQuery('your id or class or element').click(function(){
    var mainData= jQuery('your id or class or element').attr('data-id');
alert(mainData);
});
```